# Path variable having special characters like # in Spring boot

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, rest, path-variables

I'm using Spring Boot 2.4.6. For delete APIs getting 405 method not found. My endpoint is like: `beauty/v1/sites/addressTemplates/:templateId`

Path variable: #@$%#

Can someone please suggest what can be done to make this behavior as not complaining for 405? Please direct me to other questions in case I'm missing something.

Comment: Try converting your endpoint using `.toUri()`. Not exact fit but this might help you - https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-hateoas/issues/40

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I guess that your issue has nothing to do with Spring. Maybe you are trying to compose the whole URL by using **reserved** characters.

*In a URL, a hash mark, number sign, or pound sign ( # ) points a browser to a specific spot in a page or website. It is used to separate the URI of an object from a fragment identifier.* [Source](https://support.google.com/richmedia/answer/190941?hl=en#:%7E:text=In%20a%20URL%2C%20a%20hash,of%20the%20page%20or%20website.).

Which means that an URL which looks like:

`beauty/v1/sites/addressTemplates/#@$%#`

is not exactly what you imagine it to be because # is interpreted in a special way. What you have to do is to [percent encode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Percent-encoding) the "special" path variable so it will look like this at the end:

`beauty/v1/sites/addressTemplates/%23%40%24%25%23`

Then Spring will not complain anymore and will resolve properly the endpoint.